# Como utilizar html dentro de un redirect()->with

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas para poder mostrar texto en bold, cursiva y cualquier etiqueta HTML. Os dejo en detalle el código que tengo y las dudas que me surgen.

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validación
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nombrePackage' => 'required'
        ]);
        $misapp = new Misapp();
        $misapp->nombrePackage = $request->nombrePackage;
        $misapp->save();
        return redirect('/mis')->with('creadoValidadoMsg', 'Se ha creado la nueva <b>APi</b> '.$request->nombrePackage); 
    }
```

Si os fijáis quiero en **creadoValidadoMsg** en negrita la palabra API. Pero cuando muestro el mensaje de validación me lo muestra tal cual esta en el controlador.

He revisado por StackOverflow y he visto que comenta de usar lo siguiente:

```
{!! Se ha creado la nueva <b>APi</b> !!}
```

Y funciona, pero el problema es que pueden inyectar JavaScript. Por tanto supongo que algo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: El mensaje que tienes que escapar, ¿Es enviado/depende del usuario?

Comment: Pueden inyectar JavaScript si lo que el usuario ingresa va directamente como salida en tu llave `creadoValidadoMsg`, de no ser así, no habría forma en la que pudiera inyectar JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes enviar en la redirrección sólo el dato que necesitas y la parte estática (`Se ha creado la nueva <b>APi</b>`) ponerla en la plantilla `.blade.php`

Es decir en el método:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validación
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nombrePackage' => 'required'
    ]);
    $misapp = new Misapp();
    $misapp->nombrePackage = $request->nombrePackage;
    $misapp->save();
    return redirect('/mis')->with('creadoValidadoMsg', $request->nombrePackage); 
}
```

y luego en la plantilla utilizas [`@isset` por ejemplo o un `if`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements).

Algo como:

```
@isset($creadoValidadoMsg)
    Se ha creado la nueva <b>APi</b> {{$creadoValidadoMsg}}
@endisset
```

De esta forma evitas XSS.